# angular2 RC1 routing params containing dot '.'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

in a child component i use paths like this:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/axis/:prefixPath', component: AxisComponent },
    ...
])
```

A resulting link is:

```
http://localhost:3000/parent/axis/foo.bar
```

Since param prefixPath contains a '.' angular's router can't handle this case, and the server answers with "cant GET ...".

Does anyone know how to get around this ?

Comment: paste `routerLink` part where you use that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a custom [RouterUrlSerializer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b98c9e74e1ad73dc48eb67471ee91f4a1c01dfb6/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_url_serializer.ts) that does the serialization/deserialization according to your custom rules.